# Why does `date` show UTC time, even with a different timezone set?

Tags: date, timezone

I'm running Raspbian on a Pi 2. While I'm not sure this behavior was different previously, running `date` outputs the same time as `date -u`, despite my timezone being UTC-7. Below is the output of both of the above commands, and my `$TZ` variable:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ date; date -u; echo $TZ
Sat Oct  3 05:33:43 America 2015
Sat Oct  3 05:33:43 UTC 2015
America/Los Angeles
```

How can I change this output to show the correct time/date? (eg. `Oct  2 10:33:43 America 2015` as the output for `date`)

Comment: I notice there is a space instead of an underscore in "Los Angeles"; not sure if that makes a difference, but `tzselect` output has an underscore in it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have have the timezone set incorrect. To see if it works at all use some others (the extremes):

```
$ TZ=Pacific/Midway date
Mon Sep 28 20:42:02 SST 2015
$ TZ=Pacific/Kiritimati date
Tue Sep 29 21:42:48 LINT 2015
```

and if you double check your entry against the [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) you can see you're missing an underscore in the value of `$TZ`.

So try

```
$ TZ=America/Los_Angeles date
```

and see if your problem persists.

I haven't found any policy for the naming of the timezones, but spaces are never in them and replaced by underscore, but sometimes with a dash. It is probably best to look it up and copy/paste the value, something you, or your source didn't.

Comment: Looks like this is the cause of the issue, but simply `export`ing the right string doesn't seem to carry over after a system restart. `/etc/timezone` appears to have the correct string, but doesn't seem like it applies itself. Running `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` seems to replace the underscore with a space as well.

Comment: @Nightfirecat No exporting is not enough, but it is the way to test if you got the correct string without having to reboot. My system has no TZ set in the environment at all and still gets the correct timezone (from `/etc/timezone`, so it looks like one of the scripts executed on shell startup for you sets this incorrectly. Try `unset TZ` to see if that solves it.

Comment: Well, trick question -- looks like I exported the wrong `TZ` string in my .profile a while back and never realized it. My bad! :)

Comment: @Nightfirecat I just edit my previous comments while you were commenting with exact that info.